# BackboneJS + Ruby on Rails (rails-api) cross domain issues

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js, cross-domain

**Edit, updated @ the bottom**

Two domains:

Rails-api: `http://localhost:3000/`

```
/config/application.rb contains
    config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
        'Access-Control-Request-Method' => '*'
    }
```

BackboneJS: http://local.team.com/
main.js contains:

```
require([
  'app/App',
  'backbone',
  'app/Router',
  'bootstrap'
],
  function (app, Backbone, Router) {
    "use strict";

    Backbone.Model.prototype.idAttribute = "_id";

    $.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
      options.url = "http://localhost:3000/" + options.url;
      console.log('url = ', options.url)
    });

    window.MyApp = app;
    MyApp.start();

    new Router();

    Backbone.history.start();
  });
```

When a backbone model fetch is sent:

```
url =  http://localhost:3000/users main.js:45

OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/users 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.0.js:8489

OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/users Origin http://local.team.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. jquery-1.9.0.js:8489

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/users. Origin http://local.team.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. local.team.com/:1
```

At this point I'm just completely confused on which end is at fault here, I would assume Backbone. Any help greatly appreciated.

*** update ***

I'm now using the Rails-CORS gem. It works for get requests. In my config/application.rb I have:

```
# https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors
config.middleware.use Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :put, :options]
  end
end
```

GET requests, return 100% fine, no issue, post requests result in:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:3000/users. Origin http://local.team.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle additional request in your Users controller. The method type is OPTIONS. I guess you already handle GET request (index action).

Yes, the browser sends two HTTP requests. First is OPTIONS. Second is the POST or GET, the one you defined in Ajax request.

Comment: So I'd put the code in the controller:? config.action_dispatch.default_headers

Comment: @azz0r Show the development log. How does your app respond to OPTIONS and POST requests?